# Setting publisher information in visual studio express 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have a program which will *start up* when the user **logs in**. But a pop up windows shows and says ,

> This program does not have publisher info

This is very annoying. I want the program to run smoothly. Is there any way to set publisher info in Visual studio?

I have searched everywhere but could not find it.

Comment: I thought stack overflow was a programming specific site. It says anything not relating to programming should not be asked there. Anyways, Thanks for telling.

Comment: Is this so different from earlier versions? A google search for "visual studio set publisher info" immediately returned http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-specify-advanced-publishing-options-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

Comment: I seriously did a lot of searches but they did not return that page. Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on SO but there doesn't seem to be much reason to migrate it.